# CHARINDEX and LEN

Tags: sql-server

I have the string **anyname#** in the **name** column.

I need to ignore **#**.

I tried to use `LEFT (name, CHARINDEX ('#', name) - 1)` and it did not work, but using `LEFT (name, LEN (name) - 1)` works normally.

Both `CHARINDEX` and `LEN` return **integer values**.

Can you explain why I can not use **- 1** with `CHARINDEX`, but with `LEN` with it?

Comment: Something wrong on the server was preventing it from working as it should. It was restarted and then went live as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `LEFT (name,LEN(name) - 1)` will only ignore last charters.
- `LEFT (name, CHARINDEX('#', name) - 1)` will find `#` charters display position number.

in your case I would use `replace` function to  ignore **#**  `replace(name,'#','')`

Here is a sample `#` didn't display on the last charters.

```
CREATE TABLE T(name varchar(50));

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('anyn#ame');

select LEFT (name, CHARINDEX ('#', name) - 1), 
       LEFT(name, LEN (name) - 1),
       replace(name,'#','')
from t
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5550629091302dd06cf268eaa2ca0ee7)

Comment: 217/5000
yes, I know the methods, `LEN ()` will only ignore the last character, and `CHARINDEX ()` the position. But the point is that both, return me integer values, but in the `LEFT` function does not accept to be used in the same way.

Comment: @RafaelBueno In your case `LEN (name) - 1` and `CHARINDEX ('#', name) - 1` result are the same.

Comment: the values are the same but I can not use these values as the length of the LEFT function, as I have shown.

Comment: It can work the same https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5da8a8ae9456ff320ffdafe65b52d1f1

Comment: The column in my table is nvarchar and is not working. You are showing me this error: **1 Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'RAFAEL BUENO#' to data type int. **

Comment: Could you paste your code? I think the problem is on `CAST` type

Comment: Look, I do not know what happened, but I restarted the server and it's working now.

Thank you guys. It was something wrong on the server and not how the code works.

Answer (score 0):

Though not an explanation you are looking for but why can't you use `TRIM()` finction like

```
SELECT TRIM( '#' FROM  'anyname#') AS col
```

Comment: 239/5000
as you have already said, is not the explanation I seek.
My example is just to illustrate that if it were necessary to remove the last character, whatever, since I can use `LEN () - 1` and not `CHARINDEX () - 1` in the `LEFT`